# Normal and locally normal currents

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading the [Geometric Measure Theory book by H. Federer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-62010-2) and I have some questions about currents:

1. > Assuming $T \in \mathscr{D}_{m}(U),$ we call $T$ locally normal if and only if $T$ is representable by integration and either $\partial T$ is representable by integration or $m=0 .$ Furthermore call $T$ normal if and only if $T$ is locally normal and $\operatorname{spt}T$ is compact.

Now, I want to construct a locally normal current that is not normal! Does the following current work:

> $\mathbf{E}^{n} \llcorner \psi$ corresponding to all weakly differentiable real-valued functions $\psi,$ with
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \left[\partial\left(\mathbf{E}^{n} \llcorner \psi\right)\right](\phi) &=\int\left\langle e_{1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{n}, \psi(x) d \phi(x)\right\rangle d\left[\begin{array}{l}
> n \\
> z
> \end{array}\right) \\
> &=(-1)^{n-1} \int \psi(x) \operatorname{div} \xi(x) d \mathfrak{L}^{n} x
> \end{aligned}
> $$

2. > $M \subset U$ oriented submanifold, then there is a corresponding $n$-current $[M]$ defined by
   > $$
   > [M](\omega)=\int_{M}\langle\omega(x), \xi(x)\rangle d H^{n}(x), \omega \in D^{n}(U)
   > $$

Now, I want to calculate $\partial [M]$! Is it $\omega$ on $M$??

Comment: For the first one, why not just take an $m$-dimensional plane $P \subset U = \mathbf{R}^n$? Pick an orientation for it, then $[P] \in \mathcal{D}_m(U)$ has non-compact support. For the second, if $M$ has a manifold boundary $\partial M$ in $U$, then $\partial [M] = [\partial M]$. (In general the boundary of $[M]$ need not be representable by integration if $M$ were badly behaved.)

Comment: Thank you so much @Leo moos.